# React-Native Native Module 'canOverrideAnExistingModule() Error'

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've followed the React-Native Android Native Module Toast Module and I keep getting this error.

click here for image = [canOverrideAnExistingModule() Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru37V.png)

here is my code for MainApplication

```
package com.sharpsix;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new AnExampleReactPackage()
          );
       }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

Code for AnExampleReactPackage():

```
package com.sharpsix;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AnExampleReactPackage implements ReactPackage {

      @Override
      public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }

      @Override
      public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }

      @Override
      public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
                                  ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new ToastModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }    
}
```

Code for ToastModule:

```
package com.sharpsix;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
    private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

    public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
        super(reactContext);
    }


   @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ToastAndroid";
      }

    @Override
      public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
        final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
        constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return constants;
      }

    @ReactMethod
      public void show(String message, int duration) {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
      } 


}
```

lastly my MainActivity:

```
package com.sharpsix;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity{

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "SharpSix";
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain or help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your ToastModule class to something else, b'coz your overriding the ToastModule of ToastAndroid, in built class